# NVMe SSD not detected on Ubuntu install

Tags: dual-boot, radeon, amd-graphics, amd-ryzen

Last day, I was trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my friend's laptop. It's a Lenovo Ideapad S145-15api with Ryzen 7 3700u, 8GB, 128GB SSD + 1TB HDD.
The fact is that i can't install Ubuntu on the ssd because i just can't find it. There is the 1tb HDD but the SSD is not showing up.

I already tried enable/disable secure boot.

I have done a bit of of research and I found that some "Intel rapid storage technology" could be the source of the problem. But as said, it's an AMD Ryzen powered laptop.

Any idea on how to get Ubuntu to detect the SSD?

Comment: If Lenovo delivered the laptop with that SSD, they would not enable Intel RST in the BIOS; but, just in case, go in the BIOS and make sure it was not accidentally enabled, just in case. If so, change from Intel RST to ACPI, save the BIOS change, and reboot.

Comment: @K7AAY right idea, wrong execution... 'cause if they do it the way you say, Windows will no longer boot.

Comment: Is that 128G SSD used as Optane memory?

Comment: @heynnema The cpu is an amd ryzen so I don't think its Optane enabled. I saw some tutorials to make Windows boot with this change but i can't find that option on the bios.

Comment: Some need UEFI update & SSD firmware update. You also need Windows fast start up off, and UEFI fast boot off at least until reconfiguration is done. UEFI fast boot assumes no system change, so any changes may be ignored.

Comment: @oldfred I'm gonna try those options when my friend gets back from vacation and I'll give feedback.

Comment: @Ahmoled any results? same here with this lenovo and ryzen 3200u